# Authorization for Spotify API in Java HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, spotify

I'm relatively new to using http and APIs but I was trying to use HttpURLConnection in Java to connect to the Spotify API. I managed to get a GET to work but I can't figure out how to make the authorization work in order to access other materials. Here's my code, can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? It's returning a 400 response code.

```
URL url = new URL("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token?grant_type=client_credentials");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("Basic bdfc603f24c54078a7365d3af39c2aed:<ClientSecret>".getBytes()));
```

Comment: Could it be that you're not posting any content to that endpoint?

Comment: I don't think so, because it is supposed to return an access token without posting but it is just giving a 400 error.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the Content-Type, see my example.

```
URL url = new URL("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token?grant_type=client_credentials");
    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);

    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic MDg4ZDc=");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```